# How to style dialog button in NativeScript?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

My alerts and dialog buttons are white in color after i have upgraded my NativeScript version to the latest one.
Please help me retrieve its original black color...

```js
var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
 dialogs.alert({
   title: "Be Aware",
   message: "Make sure you receive money from the customer before you REDEEM.",
   okButtonText: "Customer Paid"
 }).then(function () {
   console.log("Dialog closed!");
 });
```

[Customer Paid button is white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHgP3.png)

Comment: Check your CSS files or add a new property inside your CSS to make it white...

Comment: How do i change the color back to black?

Comment: @weedoze i also tried this in the CSS: `alert{color: #000000}` but nothing changed.

Comment: Show us the html generated

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHgP3.png) Hope you can access the URL, my UI is XML not HTML

Comment: This link is the same than the one in the question... + It is not HTMl it is an image... Please show us the HTML generated via your dialogs alert

Comment: @weedoze Thanks for the tip, the alert/dialog button changes color when i change the color of an actual button, i.e Login Button.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was found in the comments.

The problem was linked to a `CSS` property generated for an other button.

This property was also affecting the button in the modal.

**Solution**

Use another class/id/selector for the modal's button

*OR*

Use the same selector than the other button and change the values inside the `CSS`